Mocking multipart request in spring is not received as multipart
So I have this test
        MockMultipartFile file = new MockMultipartFile("file", "data.txt", TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE, "data".getBytes());

    var request = multipart("endpoint")
        .file(file)

    mvc.perform(request)
        .andExpect(status().isBadRequest())
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.message").value("error"));

We are expectin a file handling exceptiopn here BUT in a HandleInterceptor
    if (!(request instanceof MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartRequest)) {
    return true;
}

This part is always activated. For whatever reason mocedRequest is not received as multipart request.
Instead it is
SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@2e9f5499]

And going like 3 layers deep with .request we can find the multipartRequest.
What is happening? Also everything works fine on a Mac but not on Windows.
